# How to include sub-classes in a Wikidata SPARQL query? (example: when querying "bands", include "rock bands")

Tags: wikidata, sparql

Here is my naive query for bridges:

```
SELECT ?item WHERE {
    ?item wdt:P31 wd:Q12280.  # Item's type is: bridge
}
```

**Problem**: It only returns a small fraction of all bridges, because [railway bridges](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Special:WhatLinksHere/Q1210334) (and all other subclasses of "bridge") are not counted.

How to retrieve all items, including sub-classes/sub-sub-classes/etc?
It MUST be with [SPARQL](https://query.wikidata.org).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The right expression to use here is `p:P31/ps:P31/wdt:P279*`.

Explanation:

- `p:P31/ps:P31` means `instance of`, or `instance of` not marked as preferred. Only using `p:P31` at this step would miss some instance.
- Following the "instance of" part, `/wdt:P279*` means this class or of any of its sub-classes/sub-sub-classes/etc

So, it means **instance of this class or of any of its sub-classes/sub-sub-classes/etc**.

The request becomes:

```
SELECT ?item WHERE {
    ?item p:P31/ps:P31/wdt:P279* wd:Q12280.  # Item's type is: bridge or sub-type or sub-sub-type/etc
}
```

[Try this query on query.wikidata.org](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fitem%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fitem%20p%3AP31%2Fps%3AP31%2Fwdt%3AP279%2a%20wd%3AQ12280.%20%20%23%20Item%27s%20type%20is%3A%20bridge%20or%20sub-type%20or%20sub-sub-type%2Fetc%0A%7D)

Comment: Then rather `p:P31/ps:P31/(p:P279/ps:P279)*`. Unfortunately, it's _very_ slow and there is no way to optimize it. One could write `p:P31/ps:P31/(p:P279|ps:P279)*` instead, relying on the Wikidata data model.

Answer (score 2):

Something like

```
SELECT  ?item  ?type ?typeLabel WHERE {
    ?type (a | wdt:P279) wd:Q12280.  # Item's type is subclass of bridge
    ?item wdt:P31 ?type.
     SERVICE wikibase:label {
    bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" .
       }
}
order by ?item
```

In this specific case it seems that all instances have a more specific type but may have multiple types.  So you may want to `SELECT DISTINCT ?item.

Correct query

```
    SELECT DISTINCT ?item   WHERE {
 {   ?type wdt:P279 wd:Q12280.  # Item's type is subclass of bridge 
     ?item wdt:P31 ?type. }
UNION
 { ?item wdt:P31 wd:Q12280.} # item is an instance of bridge 
 }
```

DISTINCT required as entities may be instances of a bridge and one of its subclasses. Logically they all should be but apparently that's not how it's done in Wikidata.

Comment: I just noticed a problem. This seems to get *only* sub-classes (so, only railway bridge, suspended bridges, but not item that are simply bridges). How to include all?

Comment: The second query does not get sub-sub-classes, for instance Suspended wooden bridges.